# Xcode Unit Test and Writing Data to Disk

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I am trying to write logic test to debug a a method that saves image data to disk.  I use the following lines to write image data to the documents directory:

```
docspath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE) objectAtIndex:0]];
fullpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docspath, _name]; 
BOOL written = [fileData writeToFile:fullpath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&dataerror];
```

Except, the data is not written and the error description returns no such file or directory.  I am running this code under a test target in the iOS 5.1 simulator.  Do I need to create intermediate directories to get to the documents directory, or is there another issue with writing to disk under a test target?

The error returned:

```
2012-06-29 16:13:31.819 otest[4597:7b03] /Users/myaccount/xcode_projects/myproject/myproject/myfolder/MMFileManager.m - 285: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1e1e3a0 {NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSFilePath=/Users/myaccount/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Documents/mmLogo.png, NSUnderlyingError=0x1e1b430 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

Comment: Reset your simulator from the options under the ios simulator tab. Clean everything and try this again...

Comment: First things I noticed: You don't need `[NSString alloc]`, use  `NSString` instead. Don't append path components manually using  `@"%@/%@"`, use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` instead to make sure the path component is properly appended.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava That didn't work.

Comment: @Anne That didn't work either.

Comment: Try substituding _name with @"test.png"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unit test is not in your app, therefore, you can't access Documents directory in the unit test.

refer to [NSHomeDirectory in iPhone unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378712/nshomedirectory-in-iphone-unit-test)