# Accessing main app data from XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, xctest

I am writing some UI tests using the new iOS 9 APIs. One thing I am running into, is when you run the tests, its its own target and own "app" on the simulator. This means I am not accessing the sqlite file I have saved in the main apps documents folder. I am having issues figuring out how to actually open this file. Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`

E.g. reading files:

```
- (NSData *)readFile:(NSString *)name withExtension:(NSString *)extension {
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:name withExtension:extension];
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:fileURL.path];
}
```

Comment: This gets me access to the bundle, not the documents folder (which is what I need)

Comment: @StephenBradley Hi. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378712/nshomedirectory-in-iphone-unit-test

Comment: Tried adding those settings, however now the UI tests fail to launch the app. Specifically on XCUIApplication().launch() I get a sigkill